# Jquerymobile UI: how to change image size within listview

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile

I have a listview of lists where each list contains an image (left) and descriptions. Just like the example: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/lists/lists-thumbnails.html

I'm trying to make the image bigger and found out that width=xxx does not take any effect. Is this size fixed for images within listview? What class can override such restriction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JQM says: To add thumbnails to the left of a list item, simply add an image inside a list item as the first child element. *The framework will scale the image to 80 pixels square.*

Try to inspect your item with firebug and override the CSS class. Should be something like: `<img class="ui-li-thumb">`

There you go:

```
.ui-li-thumb, .ui-li-icon {
    left: 1px;
    max-height: 80px; <-- height
    max-width: 80px; <-- width
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

But you have to adapt also the list size...

Comment: hey, this doesn't work for jquery 1.4.5. Any suggestions to achieve the same thing in jquery mobile 1.4.5